Removing duplicates, but deciding which to keep based on another column
I have a dataset of samples collected longitudinally, which is further divided into three time intervals. I am doing longitudinally analysis, but I am also looking at the time intervals separately. Some IDs have donated multiple samples per time interval, and I would like to remove the duplicated IDs. However, I would like to keep the samples closest to the mean time point within each time interval.
Any suggestions on how to solve this?
My dataset looks something like this:
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3), 
                 TimePoint = c(10, 12, 13, 10, 12, 11, 15, 14, 13, 12, 13),
                 TimeInterval = c("T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1",
                                  "T2", "T2", "T2", "T1", "T2"))

I have tried unique() and distinct(), but they keep the first ID they encounter

another base R option:
subset(df, ave(abs(TimePoint - ave(TimePoint, TimeInterval)), 
                ID, TimeInterval, FUN = rank) == 1)

   ID TimePoint TimeInterval
1   1        10           T1
3   3        13           T1
5   5        12           T1
6   2        11           T1
8   4        14           T2
9   5        13           T2
10  4        12           T1
11  3        13           T2


base R
df |>
  transform(meanTimePoint = ave(TimePoint, TimeInterval, FUN = mean)) |>
  transform(timeDist = abs(TimePoint - meanTimePoint)) |>
  transform(useThis = ave(timeDist, list(ID, TimeInterval), FUN = function(z) seq_along(z) == which.min(z))) |>
  subset(useThis > 0)
#    ID TimePoint TimeInterval meanTimePoint  timeDist useThis
# 1   1        10           T1      11.42857 1.4285714       1
# 3   3        13           T1      11.42857 1.5714286       1
# 5   5        12           T1      11.42857 0.5714286       1
# 6   2        11           T1      11.42857 0.4285714       1
# 8   4        14           T2      13.75000 0.2500000       1
# 9   5        13           T2      13.75000 0.7500000       1
# 10  4        12           T1      11.42857 0.5714286       1
# 11  3        13           T2      13.75000 0.7500000       1

dplyr
library(dplyr)
df |>
  mutate(
    .by = TimeInterval,
    meanTimePoint = mean(TimePoint),
    timeDist = abs(TimePoint - meanTimePoint)
  ) |>
  slice_min(n = 1, order_by = timeDist, by = c(ID, TimeInterval))
#   ID TimePoint TimeInterval meanTimePoint  timeDist
# 1  1        10           T1      11.42857 1.4285714
# 2  2        11           T1      11.42857 0.4285714
# 3  3        13           T1      11.42857 1.5714286
# 4  4        12           T1      11.42857 0.5714286
# 5  5        12           T1      11.42857 0.5714286
# 6  3        13           T2      13.75000 0.7500000
# 7  4        14           T2      13.75000 0.2500000
# 8  5        13           T2      13.75000 0.7500000

